# Connect to One-Drive using PnP-Online

Tags: windows, powershell, onedrive

I was using this code to connect to my sharepoint site to perform some file operations and it works.

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Test-Reports/"
$FolderURL= "/Documents/Abhishek" #Folder's Site Relative Path
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
```

Now, when I have to do the same thing on my one-drive, I am not able to figure out how to give the correct `$SiteURL` and the `$FolderURL` because the URL is something of this format.

> my.sharepoint.com/personal/abhishek_r_company/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?id=/personal/abhishek_r_company/Documents/Desktop

I have tried different variations but end up getting 401 unauthorized. How should I format this to be able to connect to the one-drive folder?
Can this module be used for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply this.

```
$SiteURL = "https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/abhishek_r_company/"
$FolderURL= "/Documents/Desktop" #Folder's Site Relative Path
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
```